# Error 404 : NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying with our correct url,
url is "http://localhost:9081/oscwi_eenablement/index.wss" ,still getting issue .

I tried by giving one and two active port number

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <application id="Application_ID" version="6" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">
     <display-name>TestIbmCloudEar</display-name>
     <module id="Module_1565342580069">
        <web>
            <web-uri>OSCWI_eEnablement.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>oscwi_eenablement</context-root>
        </web>
     </module> 
     </application>
```

I am getting this error instead of success login page.

> Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /oscwi_eenablement/index.wss